# C# how to execute the markup event first?

Tags: c#, markup, markup-extensions

I have this markupExtension Class

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(FrameworkElement))]
[ContentProperty("content")]
public class InsereSom : MarkupExtension
{
    public InsereSom()
    { }

    [ConstructorArgument("Ligado")]
    public bool Ligado
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("Evento")]
    public RoutedEvent Evento
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget target = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
        FrameworkElement elemento = target.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
        RoutedEventHandler metodo = new RoutedEventHandler(EventoInsereSom);



        elemento.AddHandler(Evento, metodo);

        EventInfo eventInfo = elemento.GetType().GetEvent("Click");

        FrameworkElement parentClass = (MainWindow)((Grid)elemento.Parent).Parent;

        Delegate methodDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, parentClass, "Button_Click");

        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(elemento, methodDelegate);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(elemento, methodDelegate);


        return new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
    }


    public void EventoInsereSom(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello Extension Markup");
    }
```

And this Xaml

```
<Button Width="80" Height="25" Click="Button_Click" Name="BtnTeste">
        <Cei:InsereSom Ligado="True" Evento="Button.Click"/>
</Button>
```

And this code behind

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event code behind");

}
```

I'd like that my method in my markup class execute first than the method in the code behind.

I try to add and remove the EventHandler but for that I need the event name ("Button_Click"). But cant use it hard code.

are there any other way to to id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like that my method in my markup class execute first than the method in the code behind.

It's not possible, the order in which event handlers are called can only be controlled by the class that raises the event (the button in that case). It's like a newspaper: when you subscribe to it, you can't say "I want to receive my paper before my neighbor"...

However there is a way to have the markup extension detect the click before the code-behind: you can make it handle the `PreviewClick` event (which is the [tunnelling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) version of `Click`)

Comment: I know what you say, but if you remove all handler, and add again, the event that you add int the markup class will be the first. I now one way to do it. I sent the exemple in my question. But there is one problem with my solotion, I don't know how to discover the event name to remove the handler.
Did you how to discover it?

Comment: It's not possible either, the handler could be named anything... The "Control_Event" naming pattern is just a convention, nothing enforces it.

Comment: OK, I tryed to use Xamlwriter.Save to get the XAML of the element, but they could seriazile the handler. Do you have another idea?

Comment: No, as I said, it's not possible to do that unless you handle PreviewClick instead of Click